# Nuget packages are not updated even running Update-Package -reinstall

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I would like to remove-add updated nuget packages and executed the ff:

```
Update-Package
Update-Package -reinstall
Update-Package -reinstall -Project <ProjectName>
Update-Package -Project <ProjectName>
```

None of which satisfied. Yes, they were executed but none of my packages were updated. I have to manually remove them. I don't know if it's Microsoft's scope but these are NOT WORKING..

I'm using VS2017.

Comment: NuGet works differently with `PackageReference` (PR) than `packages.config` (PC), so if your projects are PR, reinstall effectively does nothing. If your projects are PC, then what does "execute the ff" mean? `Update-Packaage -reinstall` reinstalls the same version. Did you intend to upgrade the package version instead? What problem are you trying to solve by running `Update-Package`?

Comment: getting the updated version of the package. done uninstalling - reinstalling the packages. still getting the same error. closed the soln. open. clean. uninstalling - reinstalling. still the same. removed it in config. clean. uninstall - reinstall. same.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on 'ProjectSolution' in Solution Explorer and click on 'Restore Nuget Package'

After restore, you can Update Packages

Comment: did it. still the same.

Comment: Please read the following blog. This may some help https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improved-package-restore/